# Staircase Problem Swift print "#" n and n-1 times

Tags: swift

Attempting to do the Staircase problem on Hackerrank and came up with this solution:

```swift
import Foundation

func staircase(n: Int) -> Void {
    var tag = "#"
    var i = 0
    while i < (n) {
        print( tag)
        tag += "#"
        i = i + 1
    }
}
```

[expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60JjZ.png)

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahE8k.png)

I understand that the difference is that the 7th line is empty and that's why I am getting an error. But don't quite understand the logic behind getting that extra line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminator for `print` is a newline ("\n") by default.

To avoid newline

`print(tag, terminator: "")`

Answer (score 2):

Hope this might help someone

```swift
for index in 1...n {
    let counter = n - index
    if index != 1 {
        print("")
    }
    for i in 1...n {
        if counter < i {
            print("#", terminator: "")
        } else {
            print(" ", terminator: "")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57565539/10967642), your problem is that `print` adds a new line (`\n`) at the end of the `String` you pass to it (it is the default terminator).

One solution is to construct a single `String` and print it once without the `\n` terminator:

```swift
func staircase(n: Int) {
    var str = ""
    for index in 0..<n {
        var stop = n - index - 1
        for _ in 0..<stop {
            str.append(" ")
        }
        for _ in 0...index {
            str.append("#")
        }
        str.append("\n")
    }
    print(str, terminator: "")
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).